# jQuery menu stay open after link click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, onclick

I have a jQuery menu that opens on "click" and closes on "dblclick".
http://jsfiddle.net/snoffoz/4rZa9/1/

My problem is that it (submenu) closes after I click on a link.
Is there a way to make it only open/close when clicking on the main menu points (Menu 1, Menu 2)?

EDIT: My problem will not show up in jsfiddle since the links are not real.

The "ul" "li" is generated by Wordpress.
WP link http://wptemp.site90.net/

Comment: it's not closing when I click the sublinks?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to assign the id of each menu item as a class for that item? eg. menu-item-236

Comment: yupp they are not closing after clicking on them

Comment: @Amit I think Wordpress generates it by default

Comment: Which browser are you using to view this page?

Comment: So the problem is not that the menu closes on doubleclick of menu item, and it is that it closes when the link redirects?

Answer (score 1):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/JuvwB/

If I may suggest you should try refactoring your unordered list, you had binding issue because  of the your top `ul` list `li` nest whole new `ul` i.e. horizontal menu.

This code should help you, All i did was return false when user will click on the nested list.

you can also try this: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Hope this helps, cheers!

**code**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
$(function() {

    // Dropdown Menu

    var timeout    = 100;
    var closetimer = 0;
    var ddmenuitem = 0;

    function jsddm_open() {
        jsddm_canceltimer();
        jsddm_close();
        ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible').parent().addClass('jsddm_hover').end();
    }
    function jsddm_close() {
        if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden').parent().removeClass('jsddm_hover');
    }
    function jsddm_timer() {
        closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);
    }
    function jsddm_canceltimer() {
        if(closetimer) {
            window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
            closetimer = null;
        }
    }

    $('ul.jsddm li').bind('click', jsddm_open);

    $('ul.jsddm li').bind('dblclick',  jsddm_timer);
    $('ul.sub-menu li a').bind('dblclick', function(){
        return false;        
    });
    //document.onclick = jsddm_close;

    $('.thumb img').after('<span></span>');
    $('.thumb span').css('opacity','0');
    $('.post_home a:first-child').hover(function(){



    }); 



});
})(jQuery);
```

​

Comment: Thanks for the reply @undefined
But still no dice. Every time i klick on a link the sub menu goes away.
I found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300261/submenu-stay-open-on-menu-click
But couldn't get i to work in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/snoffoz/c5nER/2/

Comment: Hiya @Snoffoz not in here: http://jsfiddle.net/JuvwB/ ? when you click the link the link will stay!

Comment: @Snoffoz this is not my answer :)

Comment: @Tats_innit I know it seems to be woking in jsfiddle bu this is only because the links are not real, only #'s.

Comment: @Tats_innit sorry, i didn't want to steal you answer bruv :P

Comment: @Snoffoz you have issue on click or dblclick, do you want to step into chat ?

Comment: @Tats_innit would be great to chat, but dont have +20 in rep =)

Comment: @Snoffoz lol I am quite new as well let me see how I can invite you for chat, else give me your wordpress site url and I will see whats going on there! :)

Comment: @Snoffoz try this bruv: http://jsfiddle.net/JuvwB/1/ lemme know if you wanna share the url for your issue!

Comment: @Tats_innit I tried your jfiddle with no success. But I uploaded my wp so you can have a look. http://wptemp.site90.net/

Comment: @Snoffoz I see, then you should show your Sub-menu on `hover` event then you can use `click` event forwarding on your main menu. You know what I mean eh?

Comment: @Tats_innit This would be a possibility if I didn't need the menue to work on an smartphone.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300261/submenu-stay-open-on-menu-click made by @TheNoble-Coder but couldn't get it working on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/snoffoz/c5nER/2/ any ideas?